# How to get stored procedure parameter types and sizes in Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

To call a stored procedure with output parameters from C#, I need to obtain the datatype and the size of the respective parameters. I am using the Oracle.DataAccess library. How can I get this information from stored procedure metadata on an Oracle database?

Someone gave the tables to query for SQL Server in this answer ([How to determine size property for stored procedure output parameters in C# data access layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395580/how-to-determine-size-property-for-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-c-sharp)), however I'm looking to call stored procedures in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the query

```sql
select  a.OBJECT_NAME, data_type, sequence, in_out, data_length, data_precision, Data_scale, radix
from USER_PROCEDURES P inner join USER_ARGUMENTS a on P.OBJECT_NAME = a.OBJECT_NAME
where a.OBJECT_NAME = 'Stored Proc name'
order by sequence
```

Comment: data_length, data_precision, Data_scale and radix all show up as NULL in my stored procedure for Varchar2 datatypes. Do varchar2 parameters not have a size? Should I set some default value for them in my C# code?

Comment: This is ok. The fun part is, when you do input parameters - no worry about setting sizes. Only for Output params you need to set size for String types (varchar2, nvarchar2, etc). Not for numbers

Comment: this is the thing about oracle - you define SP as xyz(p1 varchar2 ) <- no size, in Sql server you would need to do size. So, Oracle really has no size on parameters only types. But ODP.net OracleParameter on output needs size to determine, how many bytes retrieve. If you don't set it, you get 1. And your string "abc" will look like "a"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a little modification:

```
select  a.package_name,a.OBJECT_NAME,a.argument_name, a.data_type, a.sequence, a.in_out, a.data_length, a.data_precision, a.Data_scale, a.radix
from USER_ARGUMENTS a 
join user_OBJECTS O ON O.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
where a.OBJECT_NAME = 'your stored procname'
and o.OBJECT_TYPE in ('PACKAGE','PROCEDURE')
order by a.object_id,sequence;
```

If you have a procedure called Get_ID (for example), and you also have a procedure within a package called Get_ID, the object_name for both of them is the same, so you will get the arguments for both the "real" procedure and the procedure within the package. If you want both, then leave the two object types there, if you only want the "real" procedure, then delete 'PACKAGE'